# Get substring between tokens

Tags: c++, parsing, stl

Could you explain how to get the substring between tokens `[` and `;`

The original string:

```
a [
    b [
        text1;
        text2;
        c [
            text3;
            text4;
        ]
    ]
]
```

And that I want:

```
text1;
text2;
text3;
text4;
```

Comment: With which tool? The C++ standard library does not include parsing tools.

Comment: Of course it's possible to use those, but you'll need to build a parser on top of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick approach would be to search from the back for a `';'`, then search back for `'['`starting from that position, and split the resulting string at the semicolons. Repeat the same process until you can no longer find a semicolon `';'`.

A better approach would be to write a simple [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) with a single rule: the detection would be a lot more reliable if errors in the source are present.